# Force debug in safe mode via USB?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, rooting, usb-debugging, unbricking

I did something so stupid I'm almost kind of proud of it. I rooted my LG Optimus T (Froyo) using Gingerbreak, cleaned out a bunch of stuff, and accidentally deleted the home screen launcher. No big, I'll just install a new one... but I have a chicken and egg problem now, that requires debug mode to get out of. I can't just open settings on my phone to set debug mode. And the phone only starts up in safe mode.

So the tl;dr is this: I need to force my phone into debug mode via USB, in safe mode. If I can't do this, I will have to buy a new phone. Please help me!

Comment: With a proper Recovery (e.g. ClockworkMod) in place, and having made a proper Nandroid Backup, you should be able to restore that and start over. Or did you forget that backup?

Comment: Besides (I wasn't sure first), if your CWM is recent, it should also offer you a root shell (see [here](http://www.xperiagamer.com/Beginners-Guides/clockworkmod-recovery.html) -- so you could copy the Launcher to your SD-Card on your computer, insert it to your Optimus, launch CWM, and push the app to the system partition.

Comment: I had a Titanium Backup but it got damaged somehow. Anyway, I can't get to the screen to restore from backup either. I do not have ClockworkMod.

Comment: I see. Then the best you could probably do is to follow Michaels advice (which was what I had in mind in case you had no backup and no custom recovery, call it a "last ressort"). And make sure to include the last mentioned step, and install a custom recovery. CWM is the most used, some prefer Ammon Ra (I go with CWM).

Comment: Ultimate I did what I describe here: [I deleted my only launcher](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28871/i-deleted-my-only-launcher) but I never got it into debug mode.

Comment: Thanks for the late feedback, beth! So you were able to solve it at last, despite of that? Not that I think you're still waiting for a solution, after 3.5 years :)

Comment: Yeah I did, it's in the linked question. I linked form here in case some poor soul having the same problem stumbles on this question.

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't visited the network for more than 5 years, and no answers have score above 0). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to recover your phone is to flash the original factory firmware on it.

After much searching I found a [thread at XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=875881) which explains how to do this for the LG Optimus series phones including the P509 (yours).

You can obtain the original firmware by following [these directions](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=865479) (substituting P509 which you have for P500).

After you recover, remember that the first thing you should do after rooting a phone is to install a custom recovery (usually Clockworkmod Recovery) as this gives you access to tools to manage situations like this.

Comment: I have seen that thread before. The links to country codes and such are all dead. :(